# Label vs span: HTML

Tags: html

I am a bit confused in what to use for rendering data. My scenario is that I have to render count and I am not sure about using `span` or `label`.

```
<span id="spnCount"></span>
```

or

```
<label id="lblCount"></label>
```

Comment: Something I just learnt today:  Span content will display a caret cursor. But label content will display the normal pointer cursor. Never knew this!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

A `label` is used when you have a form or input elements - the `label` is associated with an `input` element. Span is a general container for any inline content. I think you want a `span` in this case

Answer (score 43):

## [Span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

The `<span>` tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.

The `<span>` tag provides no visual change by itself.

The `<span>` tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a part of a document.

## [Label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

The `<label>` tag defines a label for an  element.

The `<label>` element does not render as anything special for the user. However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because if the user clicks on the text within the `<label>` element, it toggles the control.

The for attribute of the `<label>` tag should be equal to the id attribute of the related element to bind them together.

Answer (score 39):

Every single person who "answered", simply copy-pasted documentation that describes the intended use-case.  However, nobody explained the differences, or the *WHY* behind why you *SHOULD* use one or the other.

The reality is, either one will technically work, so it honestly does not even matter.  You could use any number of other similar tags, including the `<i>` tag (properly styled with a class).  Assign it a unique id, use `document.getElementById()`, or use nodes, etc, do what you want.  The only people who care are semantic purists.

The label "can" and "should" be used with a form input element, true.  But it is *NOT TRUE* that it *CAN NOT* or *MUST NOT* be used in any other way.  Which means it **CAN** and **COULD** be used in other ways.

First of all, notice how `<label>` is simply used as a label "for an element".  It does not say what *TYPE* of element.  It does not say it must be an input element or a form element.  Indeed, non-form elements can have controls associated with them for provide a user experience, which perhaps manipulate objects with CSS and so on, and a label may simply connect the text to any such things.  The form could exist invisibly on page.  Who knows.

Why might it be a bad idea to use a standalone label?  If your document might exist for a long time, through several browser versions and HTML standards updates, the definition of `<label>` might change to more strictly enforce association with form input elements, then you might have a problem.  But the same is true for just about any other aspect of any of a number of specifications we rely upon just to render a page.

It's probably a very rare scenario that such a change would occur, and you'd likely not even work at the same company or on the same project team, so in all honesty, who really cares except purists?

Well, maybe anyone who is visually impaired if they rely on some technology that treats a `<label>` different than `<span>`, which could confuse the technology or the user or both.  I don't have any experience with such accessibility devices, but that might be a better reason ***WHY***.

Another valid reason is `<span>` is shorter to type than `<label>`.

And another reason might be subtle differences in the way that a search engine ranks your page or references content if using `<label>` vs `<span>`.  This is a bit of a stretch, because such algorithms are generally not publicly available, but it's possible.  One engine might produce better results one way, another engine may prefer the other way, and another engine may not care either way.

All that said, without any further knowledge of context, I'd probably go with `<span>` as it seems the *most generic* and *least contentious* way of doing things.  But I felt the question lacked a thorough **answer**, as answers usually involve a comprehension of **why**.

Comment: Excellent point about visually impaired. It's very easy to forget the accessibility factor!

Comment: Please note that comment was pure hypothetical conjecture, as I have no experience with such accessibility software.  If in fact it was true that it made a difference, it might change my final conclusion of going with `<span>` to `<label>` for accessibility.  At this point I just don't know either way and have no way of investigating further.  Further research here would be great to get definitive answers.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is a result of calculation, the [`output`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-output-element) HTML5-element probably fits best for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The  tag defines a label for an  element. If you are not using for input element, span can be used.

Answer (score 0):

A label is used in combination with a form input element. In some browsers the label can be clicked to activate the input element.

Answer (score 0):

`label` is used for labeling form controls in html. It also has `for` attribute where you can set id of the control which this label related to. `span` used in case when you need to display some literal data.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer `<span>` over `<label>` as `<span>` is generic inline container and `<label>` is for representing captions of user interface items.

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

If you had an input field, `<label>` would be better because you can use the `for`  attribute to point to the input field and the field will get focused if you click the label.

```
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text">
    <label for="agreement">Agree</label>
    <input id="agreement" name="agreement" type="checkbox">
```

Try the above code. You will see how the username field is focused when you click the label and you can also check the box by just clicking the label.

`<label>` doesn't provide any advantage in your scenario.

Also if you decide to combine your count with other interactive elements you shouldn't choose `<label>` as there is an accessibility concern.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#accessibility_concerns

Answer (score -1):

"The `<label>` tag defines a label for an `<input>` element."
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: If you spend more time at StackOverflow, you'll find that referencing to W3Schools is not a good idea, because it is [full of errors](http://w3fools.com). The particular page you link to has several errors and inaccuracies.

Comment: I've found W3Schools to be an invaluable resource, to establish basic initial understanding, and look up common syntax in reference manuals.  For some VERY RARE esoteric and advanced use cases, I have noticed errors (inaccurate or simply incomplete info), filed issues with them, and seen those issues ignore for YEARS.  MDN is Mozilla-specific, and often has errors (but it's a Wiki so I try to fix them now).  W3C creates HORRIFIC documents from a learning perspective, full of vagueness, lacking all practical use context or examples.  Those are best used by engineers creating rendering engines.

Comment: No matter if you think W3Schools is not a good resource but it has nothing to do with @CaptainCarl that you voted him down into `-2`? Anyway you can't find any other references else [W3C](https://www.w3.org/), [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com),  [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and [Google resource](https://developers.google.com/web/). So you can't simply ignore W3Schools!